# How to merge object properties and let its merging and under one object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I merge objects' properties into an object in Javascript/JQuery ?

I have the following two objects, obj & obj2:

```
var obj = {
   a: '1',
   b: '2'
}

var obj2 = {
   c: '3',
   d: '4'
}
```

I would like to merge them into something like this:

```
var obj = {
   a: '1',
   b: '2',
   c: '3',
   d: '4'
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = $.extend({},obj,obj2);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juBAc/470/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**jquery.extend()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/), it merges the contents of two or more objects together into the first object

```
$.extend(obj, obj2);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hgjtS/)

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XFB7L/3/)

**`CODE:`**

```
function merge(obj1,obj2){
var obj3 = {};
for (var attrname in obj1) { obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname]; }
for (var attrname in obj2) { obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname]; }
return obj3;
}
var obj = {
a: '1',
b: '2'
}

var obj2 = {
c: '3',
d: '4'
}
alert(merge(obj,obj2)["a"]);
alert(merge(obj,obj2)["b"]);
alert(merge(obj,obj2)["c"]);
alert(merge(obj,obj2)["d"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduction to merge many objects:

```
function merge() {
  return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(a,e) {
    for (var i in e) a[i] = e[i];
    return a;
  },{});
}

var a = {a:'a'};
var b = {b:'b'};
var c = {c:'c'};

merge(a,b,c); //=> {a:'a', b:'b', c:'c'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:--

```
var dT_1 = '{"a": "1", "b":"2"}';
var dT_2 = '{"c": "3", "d":"4"}';

var jD_1 = JSON.parse(dT_1);
var jD_2 = JSON.parse(dT_2);

var obj = $.extend({},jD_1,jD_2); // Object {a: "1", b: "2", c: "3", d: "4"}
```